# Swagger Asp.Net Core: Security for selected functions only

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, swagger-ui, openapi, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I want to create a WebAPI with ASP.net Core. The API is protected by an Authorization. But not all functions are protected!
How can I realize this with Swagger?

This are my Swagger settings:

```
[...]

builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Description = "Please enter a valid token",
        Name = "Authorization",
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
        BearerFormat = "JWT",
        Scheme = "Bearer"
    });
    options.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
    {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference
                {
                    Type=ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                    Id="Bearer"
                }
            },
            new string[]{}
        }
    });
    var xmlFilename = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
    options.IncludeXmlComments(Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFilename));

[...]

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
    {
        options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "v1");
        options.RoutePrefix = "swagger/index.html";
    });
}

[...]
```

The functions looks like this:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Registriert einen neuen User
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    /// <response code="200">...</response>
    /// <response code="400">...</response>
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Register")]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register([FromBody] UserRegistrationDto user)
    { [...] }
```

In Swagger it looks like this:

[image: Swagger index.html]

The lock indicates that an authorization is possible/necessary for this function. I want to remove the lock. But only for this function. How can I do this in c#?

(the swagger files are autogenerated and I don't want to modify the exported .yaml or.json file. So I need a solution which works directly in the c# code or in the swagger configuration.)

Comment: If register does not require authentication, why the `[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized)]`?

Could you try to add `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute?

Comment: @L01NL This is an mistake. I will remove this from the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add Operation filter for that, as well as `AllowAnonymous` to the method

```cs
public class BasicAuthOperationsFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        var noAuthRequired = context.ApiDescription.CustomAttributes().Any(attr => attr.GetType() == typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute));

        if (noAuthRequired) return;

        operation.Security = new List<OpenApiSecurityRequirement>
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
            {
                {
                    new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                    {
                        Reference = new OpenApiReference
                        {
                            Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                            Id = "basic"
                        }
                    },
                    new List<string>()
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```